# Problem with binding from style

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have this block of xaml and I made a ViewModel which contains a property called MyBrush. I would like to set the grid background to that property but this block doesn't work. Could you tell me how can I do that?

```
<Style x:Key="myKey" TargetType="myType">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="myType">
        <Grid Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                   Path=MyBrush}">
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is templatebinding, its another markup extention used to bind when in a template, see [this article](http://devlicio.us/blogs/christopher_bennage/archive/2008/07/04/templatebinding-a-bridge-between-styles-and-templates.aspx) for more
.However 
when you mention viewmodel im thinking your using it as a datacontext, if thats the case just use binding without the relativeSource expression as this is saying bind to the grid and look for property mybrush, which is a property that grid doesnt have.